# PHP - Converting an integer to a date time

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert a variable with an integer value to a 12 hour format, but It's just returning 12 am.

```
$hour = 18;

echo date('h a', $hour);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$hour = 18;
echo date('h a', strtotime("$hour:00:00"));
```

Beacause [date(format,time)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) expects a unix timestamp (seconds since the Unix Epoch, January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT). Actually, using `18` will get '00:00:18' which is `12:18 am`

Also, this will work:

```
$hour = 18;
echo date('h a', $hour*3600 ); // 1hr=3600sec
```